# dial a call and add to conference room

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

My plan is to dial a number and when the call get connected, join that call to the Conference room (565601),
but I do not have any idea how to do it.
I have tried this dial plan but it not works

```
exten => 800,1,dial(PJSIP/4141233908080249372127@US-VOS-Out)
exten => 800,n,ConfBridge(565601)
```

Comment: you should enable verbose,notice,warning log and check them To find out what happened when you call and expect to enter the conference room (565601).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second priority is executed when call ends - So nobody is joining the confbridge.

> Just use the dial flag `G` and join each ( caller and callee ) to the confbridge...

```
exten => 800,1(join_conf_call),dial(PJSIP/4141233908080249372127@US-VOS-Out,,G(2))
exten => 800,2(join_caller),ConfBridge(565601)
exten => 800,3(join_callee),ConfBridge(565601)
```

The Logic: After call is established caller goto priority 2 and callee to priority 2+1

Second example

```
exten => 800,1(join_conf_call),dial(PJSIP/4141233908080249372127@US-VOS-Out,,G(2))
exten => 800,2(caller_wait),wait(5)
exten => 800,3(join_callee_first_then_caller),ConfBridge(565601)
```

The Logic: After call is established caller jumps to priority 2 and wait 5 seconds before joining in priority 3. Callee jumps directly to priority 3.

> Last but not least...

```
exten => 800,1(join_conf_call),dial(PJSIP/4141233908080249372127@US-VOS-Out,,G(2))
exten => 800,2(caller_bye),hangup(16)
exten => 800,3(join_only_callee),ConfBridge(565601)
```

The Logic: The caller pushes callee to confbridge and leave the show (hangup) - This is usefull in cases caller wants only to join the callee to others in conference